# How do I change the Timezone on Team City 5.1?

Tags: continuous-integration, timezone, teamcity

It is building the builds at a time that is five hours ahead of the actual time.  I have remoted to the Server box and the time on it is correct.  How can I get TeamCity to build in the correct timezone?

Comment: The accepted answer does not work on my teamcity install 2017.2.2 (build 50909). I consistently see times in Sydney time although we are not connected to that zone in anyway. I have tried 'My Settings & Tools' page. I have also checked the time on the server and it is UTC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually, TeamCity shows the time in the Server's local time.

On the My Settings & Tools page, there is a setting, which enables showing times at current user local time. So if you've enabled this setting and your machine is 5 hours ahead from Server's time, you'll see time which is 5 hours ahead.

Comment: Extra details (actual at the time of TeamCity 2021.2.3): This setting is in Your Profile / General / UI Settings / the checkbox: "Show date/time in my timezone"